# JS Game - cannot set property of undefined typeerror

Tags: javascript, undefined, pacman

I know there are similar questions as mine but they did not work for my case and I can not waste more time.

I am learning JS so I am trying to code an easy pacman game. In this case, every time pacman eats a powerup, all the active ghosts have to turn into weak ghosts.

The problems comes when while I am playing and I grab a powerup, the game crashes saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isWeak' of undefined.
```

I did not post all the code in this question. Only the main part where the error comes from(I think so).

My code in main.js:

```
var activeGhosts = [];
var powerups = [];
for (var i = 0; i < powerups.length; i++) {
    if (pacman.collision(powerups[i])) {
        makeWeak();
        powerups.splice(i,1);
    }

}
function makeWeak() {
    for (var i = 0; i < activeGhosts.length; i++) activeGhosts[i].isWeak = true;
}
```

My code in ghost.js:

```
function Ghost(x,y,img){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.img = img;
this.direction = 0;
this.radius = 16; // half of 32 px because every image is 32x32 px
this.crash = false;
this.isWeak = false;

this.show = function () {
    if (this.isWeak) {
        image(weakghostimg, this.x, this.y);
    } else {
        // img can be the all the different ghosts
        image(img, this.x, this.y);
    }
};
```

Comment: How are you creating new ghosts and putting them into the activeGhost array?

Comment: I do not see link between any function.Also please show which line is throwing error

Comment: I only ask [because your code works if you add instances of new ghosts](https://jsfiddle.net/0rkjLgLo/) to the array.

Comment: The line which is throwing error is the one in the function makeWeak(). The way to create new ghosts:  ghosts.push(new Ghost(j * 32, i * 32, redGhostimg));